# simultaneous iteration fails for the 1d laplacian operator?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

The code below is to use the simultaneous iteration method to calculate the eigenvalues of the 1d Laplacian operator. The exact eigenvalues are known analytically.

It is strange that there is no convergence even after 4000 iterations. **Is it because of the degeneracy of the eigenvalues?**

If the matrix $H $ is replaced by a random hermitian matrix, things are fine.

```
clear all; close all; clc; format long 

N = 5;
H = zeros(N, N);
for s = 1 : N - 1 
    H(s,s+1)= -1 ;
    H(s+1,s)= -1 ;
end

a = rand(N,N);
[Q,R]= qr(a);
for s = 1 : 4000
    Z = H * Q;
    [Q,R] = qr(Z);
    Q;
    M= Q'* (H * Q);
    ee = diag(M);
    ee = sort(ee);
end
dd = eig(H);

[ee,dd]'
```

The final display is

````
ans =

  -1.721891779167106  -0.388948551876656  -0.000000000000000   0.388948551876656   1.721891779167106
  -1.732050807568878  -1.000000000000000  -0.000000000000000   1.000000000000000   1.732050807568877
```
````

Comment: Your matrix is not the Laplacian operator, for one.

Comment: It is related to the occurence of $\pm\lambda$ pairs. Similarly to the power method, the simultaneous iteration has a "trouble" distinguishing eigenvalues of the same magnitude. If you check $M$, you see it has two $2\times 2$ blocks, where the eigenvalues of each are the symmetrical pairs of $\pm\lambda$ eigenvalues. However, the $R$ matrix converges to a diagonal matrix as expected.